# How can I manage primitives in complex objects?

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, xna

I'm planning to use XNA to generate a model made up of multiple components.  The model is created at run time from dynamic data.  My model would be similar to a tree.  The tree has a trunk, branches, leaves, cells, etc.  I was planning to create classes for each content type such as branches that would encapsulate the leaves and so forth.

My question is where should I manage the the primitives for drawing the model?

Option 1) Each object manages it's own primitives or drawing objects.  Drawing the tree would start with a call to tree->draw which would call truck->draw which would call branches->draw and so on.

Option 2) A 'master' method would traverse the tree collecting primitives into a collection then draw the collection independent of the tree.

There are benefits to both options but which follows a typical architecture for 3d graphics?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That question really depends on the logical approach that you will use to store the data. If your tree has access to all of its children then it would be logically correct to call the `tree.Draw()` method once, and all subsequent draw methods will be called automatically according to your internal logic.

Moreover this approach can be performance efficient if you will render tree textures from a single `spritesheet` (eg. many subsequent draw calls using deferred rendering and some spritesheet(s)).